# Assign dedicated IP to vmware virtual machine

Tags: networking, ip, virtual-machine

Basically from host provider has given me:

```
IP Block:   108.61.xx.216/29
Usable Range:   108.61.xx.218 - 108.61.xx.222
Gateway:    108.61.xx.217
Subnet:         255.255.255.248
```

The host/master PC is using 108.61.xx.218 IP and I want to assign let's say IP 108.61.xx.219 to VMWare virtual machine. Both machines are using Windows.

Any ideas on what are the steps to assign the dedicated IP? I was reading about bridge mode but haven't quite found the exact steps.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Assign the static IP within the guest itself...

Comment: So am I supposed to use same subnet mask and gateway as given above?

Comment: Yes. It will work properly then.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Nathan! It's solved now! Please post an answer so I can mark it as solved :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign a static IP from within the Windows guest itself.

Answer (score 0):

each version of windows is slightly different, but you need to find your network adapter of the windows guest, change its properties (ipv4) to assign the static ip (defaults to dhcp).

i am adding a link for windows 7.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/change-tcp-ip-settings

others are similar.

yes, if you are using vmware workstation/player, you should used bridged network adapter. if you are using data center products, you need to set up the vswitches properly.

Comment: Thanks! And should I be using 'Replicate physical networking connection state' box under Bridged Networking? (In VMWare Workstation)

Comment: That is not necessary for static ip and should not affect the network settings per se. It is used for mobile devices that change the network  and thus needs to fetch a new dhcp assigned ip. This does not apply in your case.